# MVC 5 Unable to determine the principal end of an association on 0..1 to 0..1 relationship

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

I'm having problems trying to create relationships of 0..1 to 0..1
using code first between `AspNetUsers` table  extending the applicationuser class and MovieModel.
The nature of the relationship is that a user can rent one movie or not and
a movie can be rented to one renter or not. Each entity can stand by itself
and when there is no movie rented or renter the foreign fields are just `nulls`

My models:

```
public class MovieModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int MovieId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Column(TypeName="varchar")]
        [Display(Name = "Movie Name")]
        public string MovieName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Release Year")]


        public string RenterId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RenterId")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser Renter { get; set; }
```

ApplicationUser Class

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    public int? MovieId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MovieId")]
    public virtual MovieModel Movie{ get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Logically it should work. Got two foreign keys. One foreign key in `ApplicationUser` class (AspNetUser table) and one foreign key in `MovieModel`

Somehow I get this error on adding migration:`Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'VideoLibrary.Models.ApplicationUser' and 'VideoLibrary.Models.MovieModel'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotation`

Why do I get this kind of error? I don't need a principal entity in the relationship. They both can stand alone.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Code First supports 1:1 and 1:0..1 relationships. Maybe you should try "one to zero-or-one".

I removed the data annotation and created it by the model builder.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<AllesVersUser>()
        .HasOptional<MovieModel>(l => l.Movie)
        .WithOptionalDependent(c => c.Renter)
        .Map(p => p.MapKey("MovieId"));

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Tried this in my solution, and I can have movies without a renter, and users without a movie.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working finally using your code, but I had to delete and recreate the database. Any way it helped me understand how EF works.